# MySQL create function for range of values with equivalent numbers

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select-case

What is wrong with this function. Here is my expected output is

```
 1 = 10
 2 to 3 = 7
 4 to 10 = 5
 11 to 30 = 2
 31 to 100 = 1


DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `computeScore`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION  `computeScore`(`POS` INT(11)) RETURNS int(11)
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE ordinal INT;
    SELECT (
        CASE
          WHEN POS < 2 THEN 10
          WHEN POS >= 2 < 4 THEN 7
          WHEN POS >= 4 < 11 THEN 5
          WHEN POS >= 11 < 31 THEN 2
          ELSE 1
        END )
    INTO ordinal;
    RETURN ordinal;
    RETURN 0;
END;

 $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Output: I always get 10

Comment: added the output, I always get 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (
        CASE
          WHEN POS < 2 THEN 10
          WHEN POS >= 2 && POS < 4 THEN 7
          WHEN POS >= 4 && POS < 11 THEN 5
          WHEN POS >= 11 && POS < 31 THEN 2
          ELSE 1
        END )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` part should be

```
    CASE
      WHEN POS < 2 THEN 10
      WHEN POS >= 2 AND POS < 4 THEN 7
      WHEN POS >= 4 AND POS < 11 THEN 5
      WHEN POS >= 11 AND POS < 31 THEN 2
      ELSE 1
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong?

From the reference about [SELECT..INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into-statement.html) statament - *This SELECT syntax stores selected columns directly into variables. Therefore, only a single row may be retrieved.*

Check that query returns one record.

**EDIT:**

The code can be like this -

```
SET ordinal = CASE
  WHEN pos < 2 THEN 10
  WHEN pos >= 2 AND pos < 4 THEN 7
  WHEN pos >= 4 AND pos < 11 THEN 5
  WHEN pos >= 11 AND pos < 31 THEN 2
  ELSE 1
END;
```

Comment: And there is one row. No FROM is used.